# gnome-control-center crashes on 18.04 with GLIB assert error

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

Thanks for any help:

```
gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center:23766): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:47:04.571: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:23766): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:47:04.571: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:23766): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:47:04.571: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:23766): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:47:04.571: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:23766): GLib-ERROR **: 12:47:04.571: g_variant_new: expected GVariant of type '*' but received value has type '(null)'
```

output of which gnome-control-center:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center
```

output of ldd $(which gnome-control-center)

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4253f000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a2191f000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a216cb000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a213b5000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f1a20aae000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f1a207b8000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a205ab000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a2035e000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a20138000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f1a1ff2f000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f1a1fc12000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1f9ee000)
libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0 (0x00007f1a1f7d2000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1a1f49a000)
libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1f28c000)
libclutter-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1ef2d000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f1a1ed1d000)
libcheese.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.8 (0x00007f1a1eb0c000)
libcheese-gtk.so.25 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.25 (0x00007f1a1e8fe000)
libwacom.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwacom.so.2 (0x00007f1a1e6f4000)
libgnome-desktop-3.so.17 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-desktop-3.so.17 (0x00007f1a1e4b8000)
libgoa-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgoa-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1e26e000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f1a1dead000)
libgrilo-0.3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgrilo-0.3.so.0 (0x00007f1a1dc76000)
libcolord.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolord.so.2 (0x00007f1a1da56000)
libcolordprivate.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolordprivate.so.2 (0x00007f1a1d827000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1a1d489000)
libcolord-gtk.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolord-gtk.so.1 (0x00007f1a1d282000)
libsoup-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f1a1cf8f000)
libupower-glib.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libupower-glib.so.3 (0x00007f1a1cd68000)
libgtop-2.0.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtop-2.0.so.11 (0x00007f1a1cb50000)
libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1c946000)
libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1 (0x00007f1a1c6e8000)
libnm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnm.so.0 (0x00007f1a1c3eb000)
libnma.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnma.so.0 (0x00007f1a1c19f000)
libmm-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmm-glib.so.0 (0x00007f1a1bedf000)
libgnome-bluetooth.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-bluetooth.so.13 (0x00007f1a1bca0000)
libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f1a1ba14000)
libsmbclient.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbclient.so.0 (0x00007f1a1b7ef000)
libwhoopsie-preferences.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwhoopsie-preferences.so.0 (0x00007f1a1b5e5000)
libaccountsservice.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaccountsservice.so.0 (0x00007f1a1b39b000)
libibus-1.0.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5 (0x00007f1a1b134000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f1a1aeef000)
libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f1a1ac9f000)
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007f1a1aa9a000)
libcanberra-gtk3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0 (0x00007f1a1a895000)
libcanberra.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0 (0x00007f1a1a683000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f1a1a3ad000)
libpwquality.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpwquality.so.1 (0x00007f1a1a1a7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1a19f88000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1a19b97000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a19993000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1a19776000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f1a1954e000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f1a19333000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f1a190df000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f1a18ed7000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f1a18c65000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f1a18a5f000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a1882e000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f1a1852d000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a18317000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f1a18111000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f1a17f07000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f1a17d04000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f1a17b01000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f1a178c2000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f1a176ba000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f1a174b8000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f1a172a9000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1a17097000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1a16e8f000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f1a16bdb000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f1a169d2000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f1a1672d000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f1a164fb000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f1a162f8000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1a160d0000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f1a15ec3000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1a15cb9000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f1a15a35000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1a15831000)
libcogl.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20 (0x00007f1a1557a000)
libcogl-path.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-path.so.20 (0x00007f1a15368000)
libcogl-pango.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-pango.so.20 (0x00007f1a1515f000)
libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a14f38000)
libwayland-server.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007f1a14d26000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f1a14b08000)
libinput.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so.10 (0x00007f1a148ce000)
libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a14696000)
libclutter-gst-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gst-3.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a14471000)
libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a14136000)
libseccomp.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007f1a13ef1000)
libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f1a13b3a000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f1a13914000)
liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f1a136bc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1a22316000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f1a133b3000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f1a13168000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1a12f64000)
libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 (0x00007f1a1049d000)
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18 (0x00007f1a0f383000)
libgcr-base-3.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-base-3.so.1 (0x00007f1a0f0ed000)
librest-0.7.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librest-0.7.so.0 (0x00007f1a0eed7000)
libsecret-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so.0 (0x00007f1a0ec87000)
libsnapd-glib.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnapd-glib.so.1 (0x00007f1a0ea49000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f1a0e6e4000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f1a0e4dd000)
libgck-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgck-1.so.0 (0x00007f1a0e2aa000)
libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007f1a0e0a2000)
libavahi-common.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f1a0de96000)
libavahi-client.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f1a0dc85000)
libsamba-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0 (0x00007f1a0da12000)
libmsrpc3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0 (0x00007f1a0d7f2000)
liblibcli-lsa3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblibcli-lsa3.so.0 (0x00007f1a0d5ee000)
liblibsmb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/liblibsmb.so.0 (0x00007f1a0d387000)
libsamba-security.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-security.so.0 (0x00007f1a0d16a000)
libsmbconf.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 (0x00007f1a0ced7000)
libndr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr.so.0 (0x00007f1a0ccc1000)
libsamba-debug.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-debug.so.0 (0x00007f1a0cabb000)
libsamba-errors.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-errors.so.1 (0x00007f1a0c771000)
libtevent-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent-util.so.0 (0x00007f1a0c56e000)
libgse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgse.so.0 (0x00007f1a0c346000)
libndr-standard.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-standard.so.0 (0x00007f1a0be39000)
libdcerpc-samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdcerpc-samba.so.0 (0x00007f1a0babe000)
libcli-smb-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0 (0x00007f1a0b891000)
libutil-cmdline.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-cmdline.so.0 (0x00007f1a0b68c000)
libsamba3-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba3-util.so.0 (0x00007f1a0b481000)
libsecrets3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsecrets3.so.0 (0x00007f1a0b269000)
libtalloc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtalloc.so.2 (0x00007f1a0b054000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f1a0ae3f000)
libtevent.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0 (0x00007f1a0ac30000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f1a0a9f8000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f1a0a7c6000)
libpulsecommon-11.1.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-11.1.so (0x00007f1a0a548000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f1a0a2fb000)
libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0x00007f1a0a0f3000)
libtdb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1 (0x00007f1a09edd000)
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f1a09cd3000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f1a09aa1000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f1a0989d000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f1a09692000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f1a0948e000)
libcrack.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrack.so.2 (0x00007f1a09280000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f1a09033000)
libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f1a08e03000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f1a08b65000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f1a0895e000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1a08758000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f1a0853c000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f1a08221000)
libgbm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f1a08014000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f1a07e03000)
libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f1a07bef000)
libmtdev.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmtdev.so.1 (0x00007f1a079ea000)
libevdev.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.so.2 (0x00007f1a077d0000)
libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a07538000)
libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a072c4000)
libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a07089000)
libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a06e14000)
libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f1a0526b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1a04ee2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1a04cca000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f1a04a3e000)
libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f1a04801000)
libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f1a04360000)
libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f1a04155000)
libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 (0x00007f1a03f52000)
libgstapp-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a03d43000)
libgstgl-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a03add000)
libgstfft-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstfft-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1a038d2000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f1a0366a000)
libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f1a03401000)
libwebpdemux.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.2 (0x00007f1a031fc000)
libenchant.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libenchant.so.1 (0x00007f1a02ff0000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f1a02ddd000)
libhyphen.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhyphen.so.0 (0x00007f1a02bd7000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f1a028a8000)
libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f1a026a5000)
libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f1a02488000)
libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f1a0210a000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f1a01ed4000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f1a01ca0000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f1a01a1f000)
libtime-basic.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtime-basic.so.0 (0x00007f1a0181d000)
libgenrand.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgenrand.so.0 (0x00007f1a0161b000)
libreplace.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libreplace.so.0 (0x00007f1a01419000)
libsocket-blocking.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsocket-blocking.so.0 (0x00007f1a01217000)
libsys-rw.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsys-rw.so.0 (0x00007f1a01014000)
libsamba-credentials.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-credentials.so.0 (0x00007f1a00e01000)
libndr-samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libndr-samba.so.0 (0x00007f1a00ad8000)
libsamba-hostconfig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-hostconfig.so.0 (0x00007f1a008ae000)
libdbwrap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libdbwrap.so.0 (0x00007f1a006a4000)
libcliauth.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcliauth.so.0 (0x00007f1a00490000)
libdcerpc-binding.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdcerpc-binding.so.0 (0x00007f1a00271000)
libutil-tdb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-tdb.so.0 (0x00007f1a0006e000)
libsamba-sockets.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-sockets.so.0 (0x00007f19ffe56000)
libgensec.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgensec.so.0 (0x00007f19ffc2c000)
libasn1util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1util.so.0 (0x00007f19ffa26000)
libcli-cldap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-cldap.so.0 (0x00007f19ff81e000)
libCHARSET3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libCHARSET3.so.0 (0x00007f19ff61b000)
libcom_err-samba4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcom_err-samba4.so.0 (0x00007f19ff418000)
libndr-nbt.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-nbt.so.0 (0x00007f19ff203000)
libsmb-transport.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmb-transport.so.0 (0x00007f19feffd000)
libinterfaces.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libinterfaces.so.0 (0x00007f19fedfa000)
libtalloc-report.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtalloc-report.so.0 (0x00007f19febf7000)
libmessages-dgm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-dgm.so.0 (0x00007f19fe9ec000)
libsmbd-shim.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbd-shim.so.0 (0x00007f19fe7ea000)
libserver-id-db.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-id-db.so.0 (0x00007f19fe5e6000)
libiov-buf.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libiov-buf.so.0 (0x00007f19fe3e4000)
libutil-reg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-reg.so.0 (0x00007f19fe1e1000)
libmessages-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmessages-util.so.0 (0x00007f19fdfdf000)
libutil-setid.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libutil-setid.so.0 (0x00007f19fdddd000)
libtdb-wrap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libtdb-wrap.so.0 (0x00007f19fdbda000)
libserver-role.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libserver-role.so.0 (0x00007f19fd9d8000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f19fd7be000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f19fd5b8000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f19fd3aa000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f19fd158000)
libkrb5-samba4.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5-samba4.so.26 (0x00007f19fceed000)
libaddns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libaddns.so.0 (0x00007f19fcce2000)
libgssapi-samba4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libgssapi-samba4.so.2 (0x00007f19fcaaf000)
libkrb5samba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libkrb5samba.so.0 (0x00007f19fc8a3000)
libauthkrb5.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libauthkrb5.so.0 (0x00007f19fc689000)
libcli-nbt.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-nbt.so.0 (0x00007f19fc47f000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f19fc275000)
libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f19fbffc000)
libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f19fbdf6000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f19fbbcb000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f19fb9c2000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f19fb795000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f19fb580000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f19fb2ca000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f19fb04e000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f19fae1d000)
libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f19fac1a000)
libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f19faa0e000)
libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f19fa80a000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f19fa608000)
libsamdb-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0 (0x00007f19fa3dc000)
libldbsamba.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba.so.0 (0x00007f19fa1b0000)
libldb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldb.so.1 (0x00007f19f9f81000)
libwbclient.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwbclient.so.0 (0x00007f19f9d73000)
libsamba-modules.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamba-modules.so.0 (0x00007f19f9b70000)
libsamdb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamdb.so.0 (0x00007f19f9958000)
libcommon-auth.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcommon-auth.so.0 (0x00007f19f9750000)
libcli-ldap-common.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-ldap-common.so.0 (0x00007f19f9548000)
libmsghdr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsghdr.so.0 (0x00007f19f9345000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f19f912a000)
libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f19f8ee9000)
libheimbase-samba4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libheimbase-samba4.so.1 (0x00007f19f8ce5000)
libasn1-samba4.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libasn1-samba4.so.8 (0x00007f19f8a6c000)
libhx509-samba4.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhx509-samba4.so.5 (0x00007f19f8826000)
libhcrypto-samba4.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libhcrypto-samba4.so.5 (0x00007f19f85f4000)
libroken-samba4.so.19 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libroken-samba4.so.19 (0x00007f19f83e7000)
libwind-samba4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwind-samba4.so.0 (0x00007f19f81bf000)
libndr-krb5pac.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libndr-krb5pac.so.0 (0x00007f19f7fb1000)
libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f19f7d3a000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f19f7a91000)
libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f19f7871000)
libflag-mapping.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libflag-mapping.so.0 (0x00007f19f766f000)
libwinbind-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libwinbind-client.so.0 (0x00007f19f746b000)
libMESSAGING-SEND.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libMESSAGING-SEND.so.0 (0x00007f19f7268000)
libjansson.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4 (0x00007f19f705a000)
libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f19f6e51000)
libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f19f6bc4000)
libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f19f6922000)
libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f19f66ec000)
libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f19f64d6000)
libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f19f62ad000)
libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f19f609e000)
libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f19f5e54000)
```

Comment: Please add output of `which gnome-control-center` and `ldd $(which gnome-control-center)` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I've added the output to the post, thanks for your help

Comment: The `libXinerama.so.1` may cause problems. Consider to move `/usr/local/lib/libXinerama.so.1` out the way with `sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libXinerama.so.1 ~/`. And try again.

Comment: thanks @N0rbert but no luck: (gnome-control-center:4041): GLib-ERROR **: 08:27:38.944: g_variant_new: expected GVariant of type '*' but received value has type '(null)'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)